# Mui v5 Grid system

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid

How to create a grid system like the picture below ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIz4l.png)

On the left is normal desktop view, and the right is for mobile view.
Actually I can use `sx={{ display: {xs: "none", sm: "none", md: "block"} }}` to do it, but I wander is there have any other way to do so ?

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={7} order={{ xs: 1, sm: 1, md: 0 }}>
        1
    </Grid>

    <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={5} order={{ xs: 0, sm: 0, md: 1 }}>
        2
    </Grid>

    <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={5} order={2}>
        3
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

As the code above, its can work fine in mobile view, but on the desktop view the third grid item are below the seconds grid item.

Because of that, I tried to add another grid item after the second grid item:

```
{first grid}
{second grid}

<Grid item xs={0} sm={0} md={7} order={2} />

<Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={5} order={3}>
    3
</Grid>
```

Yes, its work, but the first grid item actually is dynamic height, when it become longer, the third grid item were push to bottom.

Comment: Could you add a small workable eg on codesandbox or related platform

Comment: What you're looking for is a masonry grid. https://mui.com/material-ui/react-masonry/